# How do I use user input in an if-else statement and how do I loop the code back around if the user input is not what is asked for?

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement

(Any text now in this question is from after the answer to my question was selected)

This is the code given for my problem. I wanted the code to perform certain tasks whenever the user input "Yes" or "No", so I needed to know how to implement the user input into an if-else statement. I also wanted to find out how to loop the code back to the user input of anything other than "Yes" or "No" was entered.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RandomPerkSelector {

    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you playing as a survivor?");
   }
}
```

Comment: *`How do I use strings from user input in an if-else statement that leads to picking 4 random numbers 1-56?`* Could you elaborate more on what you mean by this? How will the `String` affect the 4 random numbers? Why do you need an `if/else`?

Comment: Try to split your task in smaller steps and tell us which step you have problem with. For instance (1) reading user choice (2) checking if it is option A or B (c) picking n distinct numbers in a range. Those questions ware already answered here, try to search for them and if you still have some problem with it describe it in more details.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can u explain in another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to use your `Scanner` to read from the keyboard. You are already half-way there:

```
Scanner userInputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = userInputReader.nextLine();
```

You can simply check if the `userInput` is equal to `yes`/`no` like this:

```
if(userInput.equals("yes")){ //note strings are compared with .equals, not ==
   //"yes" case
}else if(userInput.equals("no")){
   //"no" case
}else{
   //neither "yes" nor "no"
}
```

Alternatively a switch statement also works

```
switch(userInput){
   case "yes":
      //yes case
      break;
   case "no":
      //no case
      break;
   default:
      //neither "yes" nor "no"
      break;
}
```

Making it ask for more inputs if an invalid one was given:

```
while(true){
    String userInput = userInputReader.nextLine();
    if(userInput.equals("yes")){ //note strings are compared with .equals, not ==
       //"yes" case
       //generate your numbers for "yes"
       break;
    }else if(userInput.equals("no")){
       //"no" case
       //generate your numbers for "no"
       break;
    }else{
       //neither "yes" nor "no"
       //note that the continue statement is redundant and 
       //the whole else-block can be omitted
       continue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: And how might I redirect it to ask again if it is neither "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Since (in your particular case) it is the first thing you do in `main`, you could just start main over by calling it again: `main(args);`. In the general case you would probably want to move it to its own function and follow the pattern from there. Or you could just put the statement in a `while(true){ ... }` and break on yes/no but not on anything else.

Comment: within else part call scanner.next() again

Comment: Added the the asking-again part to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to input just "yes"/"no" and asking them to input again until they get it right, you can use a do while loop. After that, you can using a switch statements to control your program flow. Like this

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    do{
        System.out.println("Input : ");
        userInput = sc.nextLine();
    }while("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)==false && "no".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)==false);
    switch(userInput){
        case "yes":
            //do something
            break;
        case "no":
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            //do something
            break;

    }
```